# Overloading C++ STL methods

Tags: c++, stl, overloading

How can I overload the STL implementation for methods like find, erase and insert to take varying parameters? I tried to look up the overloading of STL methods but couldn't find any help.

Comment: You _do_ mean overloading?  As in std::for_each( iter1, iter2, fc )?  Or are you talking about overriding, as in vector::find, map::erase etc...?

Comment: Presumably you mean C++ Standard Library, not STL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't overload the methods of a class without editing the code of that class.

Write your own free functions that act as helpers; they would take the relevant container class as the first parameter.

You can inherit from a class and add methods that way, but the std container classes are not designed to be inherited from.

Comment: to explain: destructing a derived object via pointer to base with a nonvirtual dtor is strictly UB. And the std container classes have nonvirtual dtors because they don't want a vtable. The STL is designed for static polymorphism so the suggested solution is to [..]

Comment: [..] just make a class that conforms to the same concept as vector and pass instances of that to function templates. Whether this is practical is arguable.

Answer (score 3):

You are not allowed to add overloads in the std namespace. Only specialization of functions and algorithms for your own data types are allowed. If you do want a different find, erase, insert... implement a wrapper (out of the std namespace) and use it.

And I would not recommend it either... What kind of overloads do you want to provide?

Comment: just having custom arguments each of different type

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to do this; the standard prohibits it.