# C++ ostream overloading not working

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, iostream

**Edit:**

After some comments, this is my code now, following [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx) link.(Better, but I still have an error)

Out of everyhing:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Device& v) {
    out << "Device " << v.get_name() << " Has an ID of: " << v.get_id();
    return out;
}
```

Inside Device class:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Device& v);
```

My call: (device is of type Node, and val returns the device)

```
cout << device->val << endl;
```

My error:

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol
>   "class std::basic_ostream >
>   std::char_traits > & __cdecl operator<<(class
>   std::basic_ostream > &,class Device
>   const &)"
>   (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABVDevice@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "void __cdecl print_devices(class Node *)"
>   (?print_devices@@YAXPAV?$Node@VDevice@@@@@Z)

**Original:**

I was taught that overloading an operator is made like this:

```
ostream& Device::operator<<(ostream &out) {
    out << "Device " << this->name << " Has an ID of: " << this->id;
    return out;
}
```

But when trying to use this overloading - (device is type Device)

```
cout << device << endl;
```

It marks in read and says -

> Error C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'Device' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Why do I get this error, and how can I fix it? I looked online, but could not find a method that works inside the class, only this:

> friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Point &cPoint);

Which did not work for me as well.

Comment: _"Which did not work for me as well"_ How it didn't work for you specifically? You need the global operator overloaded like this: `ostream& operator(ostream& out, const Device& dev)`.

Comment: Ok, without "<<" and not within the class?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo: `ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Device& dev)`, yes outside of the class.

Comment: I get the exact same error. `ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Device& v) {
 out << "Device " << v.get_name() << " Has an ID of: " << v.get_id();
 return out;
}`

Comment: Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx "Overloading the << Operator for Your Own Classes". If you do that right it should work.

Comment: define the (free) overloaded operator in the std namespace or in the namespace of Device, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

Comment: @AAT I edited the post with the new code. It still does not work, but now I have a different error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have declared inside your `Device` class is

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Device& v);
```

but what you have provided the implementation for is

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Device& v) {
    out << "Device " << v.get_name() << " Has an ID of: " << v.get_id();
    return out;
}
```

which is **not the same thing**! You told the compiler there is a `friend` function which takes a reference to an `ostream` and a **const** reference to a `Device` - but the function you have provided misses the `const` in front of `Device`.

Comment: oh god I didnt notice it! I changed it all to const, but then came tens of errors, so im using the non-const value - Device& v. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

[Overloading C++ STL methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696320/overloading-c-stl-methods)

I'm not convinced you can overload the << operator on an STL stream based on this answer.

Comment: Here is a Microsoft guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx
It is possible. (its in my homework..), I just cant make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The error you've posted is about the compiler not finding the function implementation.

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyType
{
    int data{1};

};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const MyType& t)
{
    out << t.data;
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    MyType t;

    std::cout << t << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```